# Flatlist adding unwanted blank spacing between rendered components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

My react native application has a flatlist that renders new components with the press of a "+" button.

I have a state:

```js
const [numWorkouts, setNumWorkouts] = useState([1]);
```

The plus button will update this state on press:

```js
<TouchableOpacity
          style={tailwind("w-[100%] items-center")}
          onPress={() => {
            setNumWorkouts(numWorkouts => [...numWorkouts, numWorkouts.length]);
          }}
        >
```

Also have this useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => { updateNumWorkouts()}, []);
```

That calls this function:

```js
const updateNumWorkouts = newWorkout => {
    let s = newWorkout === undefined ? 1 : newWorkout;
    let tempArr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < s; i++) {
      tempArr.push(i);
    }
    setNumWorkouts(tempArr);
  };
```

Here is how the list is being rendered:

```js
     <FlatList
        data={numWorkouts}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return <LoggingComponent index={index} updateArr={addWeight} pushWID={pushWID}/>;
        }}
      />
```

This same logic works fine in other areas of the app where a button press will render one more of a component. However in this screen, it renders random space between the component and the plus button.

**Here are examples:**

[Here is what the spacing looks like after pressing the plus button once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bs2Ul.png)

[This is what it looks under this component - some unwanted spacing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKRaK.png)

[The spacing grows bigger as you click the plus button more times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWhHq.png)

Would love some help on this, willing to share more info as needed!

Comment: Please show how you render the list as well :)

Comment: Just added to post!

Comment: what is tailwind in touchableOpcity?

Comment: Tailwind is just the styling library. It's basically saying "width-100%, alignItems: center"

Comment: the issue could be something to do with the stylings you have applied to LoggingComponent or the parent component